# Python indention issue that isn't due to improper whitespace

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm getting an indention error in the following code:

```
 28 def dropletExistsInSummaries( droplet ):                                                                                                                             
 29   """                                                                                                                                                                
 30   dropletExists() -- checks to see if a droplet's URL exists in the summary table, takes one argument                                                                
 31   * droplet is the DID of the raindrop                                                                                                                               
 32   """                                                                                                                                                                
 33   log.debug( "entering" )                                                                                                                                            
 34   c2 = db.cursor()                                                                                                                                                   
 35   d = ( droplet, )                                                                                                                                                   
 36   did = 0                                                                                                                                                            
 37   try:                                                                                                                                                               
 38     c2.execute( 'SELECT did from summaries where did = ?', d )                                                                                                       
 39     did = c2.fetchone()[0]                                                                                                                                           
 40   except Exception, e:                                                                                                                                               
 41     log.error( "dropletExists query failed: %s", e )                                                                                                                 
 42   if did > 0:                                                                                                                                                        
 43     return did                                                                                                                                                       
 44   else:                                                                                                                                                              
 45     return 0                                                                                                                                                         
 46                                                                                                                                                                      
 47                                                                                                                                                                      
 48 def summarizeDroplet( did, url ):                                                                                                                                    
 49   """                                                                                                                                                                
 50   TODO: document this                                                                                                                                                
:x                                                                                                                                                                      
sodaphish@svr-lnx02:~/semanticrss$ ./tst.py 
  File "./tst.py", line 37
    try: 
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

...which doesn't make any sense to me because I've checked to make sure everything is properly indented!  I've stared at this for hours and am resigned to the fact that I need have help.

To be completely honest, I'm not entirely sure why I had to surround "droplet" with parens at line 35, and my guess is that's what's causing the problem, but I can't tell you with certainty that the issue is related to that.

For the record, I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you use an editor that does autoindenting, you can often get a big clue by having the editor tell you how it thinks your program should be indented.

Comment: Please get rid of the line numbers

Comment: I guess that's a punishment for defining a tab to be 2 spaces instead of 4... ;)

Comment: You are almost certainly mixing tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your function indent is three spaces, while the indentation of your `try...except` block is two spaces. Fix this and it should work.

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recommends four spaces for indenting code, though.